# assembleRelease.dependsOn test for allprojects

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

im trying to run test task before android's assembleRelease

App has multiple modules.

In single module app I used to do it via

```
afterEvaluate {
  println tasks
}
```

in app/build.gradle

This does not work anymore for multimodule, i.e. it only runs tests on app module. So I need that block inside every module's build file, which is error prone

So I tried globally in root build file

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.findByName("assembleRelease").dependsOn tasks.findByName("test")
    }
}
```

This however fails that those tasks cannot be find, i.e. they're not present in `println tasks` anyways.

Anybody have idea where to get reference to them? Or better, how to run root test task before root assembleRelease?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell me why you are not using the `build` task?

Comment: I didnt know youre supposed to create custom build task with assembleRelease + test, I like it but doesnt work for me. In which file should I put this task? I tried root but it doesnt know test task there..